# Create complete site programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, application-pages, office-365

I want to create a complete site in Visual Studio (Sandbox solution), so it is easy to deploy (with one press on the button on site collection level) to Office 365 / SharePoint Online.

I can create my site and subsites, but when I can not figure out how to get my application pages in the correct subsite/Pages library of an other subsite...

When I first put my application page in a folder, I get an error that the subsite can not be created because the folder already exists.

But, When I first create my site structure, it is also not possible to get my application page in the correct subsite of another subsite.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the client object model to create my site.
It reads the complete structure from site A
and recontstructs it on site B.

Works nice :-)

Answer (score 4):

Application pages are not allowed in Sandboxed solutions.

So all pages have to be site pages, deployed through modules. These modules can then be added to features which can be activated on the difference sites depending on which pages is needed on each site.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it were site pages. ;-)

But I solved it with a work around. :-)
First I place my pages in the site collection in a temp folder; and then move / copy the files to the subsites Pages Library.

Answer (score 1):

I think WebTemplates would have been your best option. They work perfectly in SharePoint Online / Office 365 /Sandbox Solutions. Here is a detailed and extensive post on them:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   But I solved it with a work around. :-) First I place my pages in the site collection in a temp folder; and then move / copy the files to the subsites Pages Library.

Why don't you use features and modules?
In this case it's better to create feature with "Web" scope and add a module with necessary site pages. Since you have a web-scoped feature, you can activate this feature on different web-sites to deliver the site pages to site libraries.